# Archive page if else not working for post_excerpt and post_content

Tags: php, archives, excerpt

I want to show the excerpt from a post only if it exists. If it does not I want to show an excerpt of the content text of the post. Here is what I came up with:

```html
<?php

  $my_excerpt = $item->post_excerpt;

  if ($my_excerpt) {            
    echo Str::limit($my_excerpt, 120);
  }
   else
  { 
    $content = ($item->post_content);
    $contentexcerpt = substr($content, 0, 150);
    echo $contentexcerpt, '...'; 
  }
?>
```

This worked perfectly until I tried to use it on an archive page inside a foreach loop. Now it shows both the custom excerpt and an excerpt taken from the content text.

Here is the code for the whole archive page
[archivepage](http://pastebin.com/7Z66KcQr)

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not seeing the part "<p><?php echo Str::words($queried_post->post_content, 19); ?></p>" at line 46 in your archive page? Do you have a link to your page, so we could inspect it?

Comment: Please add your complete code inside your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the horribly format issues you also have a typo:

```
<?php
            $my_excerpt = $item->post_excerpt;

                        if ($my_excerpt){                      
                        echo Str::limit($my_excerpt, 120);}

                        else
                        $content = ($item->post_content);{
                        $contentexcerpt = substr($content, 0, 150);
                        echo $contentexcerpt, '...';
                        }
         ?>
```

These lines:

```
else
                            $content = ($item->post_content);{
```

should be:

```
else {
                            $content = ($item->post_content);
```

The parser registered a single line of code corresponding to the `else` statement, mainly this: `$content = ($item->post_content);`

After that, the code between the curly brackets:

```
{
                        $contentexcerpt = substr($content, 0, 150);
                        echo $contentexcerpt, '...';
                        }
```

is treated like any other block of code and that is why if the `if ($my_excerpt)` conditioned is passed it will still output the custom excerpt.